# java chat app running client file by calling from another file not working

Tags: java, client-server, chat

I am working on a project which is a multi client chat app when I running my client file directly it is working fine 
but when I am trying to calling it from any other(for say new jframe) file it is not working .

ChatClientGuiTEST.java

```
    enter code here
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package chating;

import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;

/**
 *
 * @author Hello
 */
public class ChatClientGuiTEST extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;
    ResultSet rs;
    //SignUp obj;

    public ChatClientGuiTEST() throws IOException {
        initComponents();
        pack();
        setSize(406, 600);
        setResizable(false);

        //jLabel2.setText(usern);
        jLabel2.setVisible(true);
        //jTextArea1.setVisible(false);

        jTextField1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (jTextField1.getText().trim().length() != 0) {
                    try {
                        out.println(jTextField1.getText());
                    } catch (Exception ev) {
                        System.out.println(ev);
                    }
                    jTextField1.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
        jTextField1.requestFocusInWindow();

        try {
            connection obj = new connection();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM tb_online";
            connection.pst = connection.con.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = connection.pst.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {

                String online_user = rs.getString("online_user");
                Object[] row = {online_user};
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
                model.addRow(row);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "UNABLE TO FETCH DATA" + e, "ERROR", 0);
        }
        this.setVisible(true);
        //run();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jTextField1);
        jTextField1.setBounds(0, 530, 400, 40);

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jTextArea1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(4, 400));
        jTextArea1.setSelectionColor(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 51));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);
        jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
        jTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
        DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)jTextArea1.getCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1);
        jScrollPane1.setBounds(0, 70, 400, 460);

        jLabel2.setText("jLabel1");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2);
        jLabel2.setBounds(340, 390, 50, 14);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Urdu Typesetting", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel1.setText("WELCOME          USER          TO          CHATZONE");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1);
        jLabel1.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 30);

        jButton1.setText("LOAD PREVIOUS MESSAGES");
        getContentPane().add(jButton1);
        jButton1.setBounds(3, 40, 170, 23);

        jButton2.setText("VIEW ONLINE USER");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton2);
        jButton2.setBounds(190, 40, 160, 23);

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "ONLINE"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.String.class
            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable1);
        if (jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
        }

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane2);
        jScrollPane2.setBounds(400, 70, 100, 500);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jTextField1ActionPerformed

        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jTextField1ActionPerformed

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed
        if (jButton2.getText().equals("VIEW ONLINE USER")) {
            // jTable1.setVisible(true);
            setSize(500, 600);
            jButton2.setText("HIDE ONLINE USER");
        } else {
            //   jTable1.setVisible(false);
            jButton2.setText("VIEW ONLINE USER");
            setSize(406, 600);
        }

// TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed
    public void run() throws IOException {
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9001);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        while (true) {

            String username = "abc";
            //jLabel2.getText().toString();
            String line = in.readLine();
            if (line.startsWith("GETNAME")) {
                out.println(username);
            }
            if (line.startsWith("MESSAGE ")) {
                String msg = line.substring(8);
                jTextArea1.append(msg + "\n");

            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    // public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ChatClientGuiTEST client = new ChatClientGuiTEST();

       // client.setVisible(true);
        client.run();
    }


    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

ChatServerGui.java

```
package chating;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ChatServerGui {
    ResultSet rs;

    private static final int PORT = 9001;

    private static HashSet<PrintWriter> writers = new HashSet<PrintWriter>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("The chat server is running.");        
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        try {
            while (true) {
                new Handler(listener.accept()).start();

            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
        }

    }

//    public  static void startServer()throws IOException{
//    System.out.println("The chat server is running.");        
//        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
//        try {
//            while (true) {
//                new Handler(listener.accept()).start();
//               
//            }
//        } finally {
//            listener.close();
//        }
//    }

    void setVisible(boolean b) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private static class Handler extends Thread {





        private Socket socket;
        private BufferedReader in;
        private PrintWriter out;

        public Handler(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {

                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                writers.add(out);
                while (true) {
                    out.println("GETNAME");
                    String name = in.readLine();

                    String input = in.readLine();
                    if (input == null) {
                      return;
                    }
                    try{
                        connection obj = new connection();
                    String query="INSERT INTO tb_msg (msg) VALUES('"+input+"')";
                    connection.pst = connection.con.prepareStatement(query);
                    int rst = connection.pst.executeUpdate();

                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR THERE MIGHT BE PROBLEM IN DATABASE","ERROR",0);
                    }
                    for (PrintWriter writer : writers) {
                        writer.println("MESSAGE "+name +":"+ input);
                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } 
//            finally {
//                
//                if (out != null) {
//                    writers.remove(out);
//                }
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
//}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to add some code showing what you have tried.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, if you have any errors in the console, it would be great to add it also. Try to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it will help you

Comment: Your question must have more detail than "it's not working."  Describe exactly what behavior you expected to see, and what behavior you are observing instead.  If an exception is occurring, include the *entire* stack trace in your question, and include the code where that exception occurred.

Comment: its look like it is got hanged or stuck at a point i dont get any kind of exceptionn

Comment: The server or the client?

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a wild guess here. In your server file, you create tons of threads in the while true loop. As they are separated threads, the main thread execution is not stopped, so you are basically filling your JVM memory.

```
while (true) {
    new Handler(listener.accept()).start();
}
```

The reason why you don't get OOM error is because your thread ends as soon as it starts because of this:

```
while (true) {
    out.println("GETNAME");
    String name = in.readLine();

    String input = in.readLine();
    if (input == null) {
        return; // <-- Ends the while loop and the run function, thread dies
    }

// ...
```

You should be using `continue` instead of `return` which skips the rest of the loop code. If you do, though, you JVM will explode in no time! Do you really need tons of `Handler`?

There is also your `connection` and `PreparedStatement` instances that don't get closed properly and I'm not quite sure creating new connections each time you get a message is the way to go.

Comment: 1.   I dont need tons of handler but i need a  handler if a new client get connected to server it will handel its request . 2.yes the error is in tht while loop when we give it a particular condition like a<2 than the code is work for two time 3. My question is when i run the client file directly why it is work fine . 4. Yes preparedStatement not closed properly but i have not complete my work on that till now .

Comment: I try to change from return; to continue; but it is also not working